# Every time I try to install Ruby 3.1.2 via Ubuntu for WSL, my computer crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Every time I try to install Ruby 3.1.2 using RBENV and the Ubuntu app for windows, my computer crashes.  When I look carefully, it appears to be some type of 'kernel error'.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a kernel update to WSL.

You can do it here: https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel

Go to the link above and then click that link you see in the photo below.  It will download the package and update the kernel files.

https://gyazo.com/c4a11557da1a77bd694eb8db778bb7e7

Then, make sure your system is set to WSL2 (just keep following the instructions).

If you run into other errors, here are some other helpful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417663/error-installing-ubuntu-22-04-on-wsl

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10